# Escape Analysis with std::vector in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, escape-analysis

I am wondering there is any optimization option in Clang or GCC for escape analysis on `std::vector` in C++.
Since `std::vector<int>` in the example below does not require the actual data of `v` to be allocated in the heap or stack. Compiler can actually allocate `v.data()` on stack for better performance.

1. Assume that Clang/GCC does not do escape analysis, is there any particular motivation to not to use escape analysis?
2. Assume that Clang/GCC does escape analysis, why value of `v.data()` and `&x` so different?

```cpp
#include<cstdio>
#include<vector>
int main() {
    int x = 0;
    std::vector<int> v(3, 0);
    std::printf("&x: %p\n", &x);
    //std::printf("&v: %p\n", &v); // we intentionally don't print the pointer to v here.
    std::printf("v.data(): %p\n", v.data());
    return x + v[0]; // we want compiler not to optimize everything out
}
```

Expected result

```
&x: <some address>
v.data(): <some address> + 4
```

Actual result from Clang and GCC

```
[*****@localhost test]$ g++ test.cc -O3
[khanh@localhost test]$ ./a.out 
&x: 0x7ffe2af5a59c
v.data(): 0xadde70
[*****@localhost test]$ clang++ test.cc -O3
[*****@localhost test]$ ./a.out 
&x: 0x7fff66ce1ab4
v.data(): 0xfeee70
```

Thanks!

Comment: "does not requires to be allocated in the heap" - why not?

Comment: Compare with Golang / JAVA, the equivalent code, that array will not be allocated on Heap.

Comment: If you want a statically sized list on the stack, why not use a c-style array?

Comment: @Ezphares Sure, either use `c-style array` or `std::array`, my question is about compiler optimization.

Comment: "why the address of actual data of v and x is so different?". Because `v.data()` is allocated on the heap. What do you want to actually ask? Why doesn't the compiler optimize `v.data()` to be allocated on the stack?

Comment: It is wrong to compare `vector` class from C++ (which allocates memory using specified allocator) with built-in arrays in Golang / JAVA. Go actually allows only static size arrays so equivalent c++ coude would be `int items[size]{};`, while java does not allow static size arrays at all so equivalent c++ code would be `int * p_items{new int[size]{}};`

Comment: @VTT is there some misconception from you?
In JAVA, arrays and objects are allocated on `JAVA heap`, the exact memory region will be used is decided by compiler.
In Golang, you can try with `go build -gcflags "-m"` to see which objects are allocated on heap or stack. Slices are dynamic size arrays (not hashable) can also be allocated on stack.

Comment: Clang does some optimization around `new`, but I think if you use the address of the memory block, it will generate a `operator new` call.

Comment: @geza Can you provide some examples with code? There are some blogs mentioned about escape/capture in llvm but I haven't found one in the official website.

Comment: Here's one example: https://godbolt.org/z/N1GLUI. I'm not sure that you're after this, but this is an example, where clang optimized away `operator new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists escape analysis on Clang compiler.

Sample code: from @geza https://godbolt.org/z/N1GLUI

```cpp
int fn(int a, int b, int c) {
    int *t = new int[3];

    t[0] = a;
    t[1] = b;
    t[2] = c;

    int r = t[0]+t[1]+t[2];

    delete[] t;

    return r;
}
```

GCC

```
fn(int, int, int):
  push r12
  mov r12d, edx
  push rbp
  mov ebp, esi
  push rbx
  mov ebx, edi
  mov edi, 12
  call operator new[](unsigned long)
  mov DWORD PTR [rax], ebx
  add ebx, ebp
  mov rdi, rax
  mov DWORD PTR [rax+4], ebp
  mov DWORD PTR [rax+8], r12d
  add r12d, ebx
  call operator delete[](void*)
  mov eax, r12d
  pop rbx
  pop rbp
  pop r12
  ret
```

Clang

```
fn(int, int, int):                               # @fn(int, int, int)
        lea     eax, [rdi + rsi]
        add     eax, edx
        ret
```

Comment: Note that gcc performs the same optimization since version 11